# How much money did Jason Bourne have in the red bag during Bourne Identity?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-identity

This may seem trivial but I've always been curious how much money Jason Bourne had to work while on the run during The Bourne Identity. He basically threw Marie 10k to drive him to Paris, then said he'd give her another 10k when they got there. Also, he gave Marie enough to start or buy a shop near the beach when she went into hiding, plus probably had some left over for himself.

Is there any info that would help determine how much he actually had with him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A Million Dollars (almost)

The [**script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/bourneidentity.html) confirms it.

> Lifting the top tray.
>
> Staring into THE DEEP BOTTOM TRAY and --
>
> First of all...
>
> MONEY.  Lots of it.  Ten thousand dollar stacks of hundreds. Lots of them.  **Close to a million dollars.**  There's A GUN. A very good gun.  Several clips of ammo.  And...
>
> FIVE MORE PASSPORTS.  All clean.  Crisp.  Brand new.  All with his photo inside. Five different names. Three different Countries.

---

> BOURNE into gear.  Looking around the room -- there -- there's a pile of red canvas burn bags in the corner.
>
> BOURNE grabbing one -- stuffing **everything** into it -- everything except...
>
> The gun.  He doesn't want the gun.  No guns.

Comment: That's definitely a "reading" script! When I wrote scripts, they were much more dry.